# Node.js- scan DynamoDB AWS- adding parameters

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I get data from dynamoDB with Lambda AWS. I try to add parameter to my parameters which I send to Lambda from android app:

```
if (typeof event.high_lat != "undefined") {
            params.ExpressionAttributeValues = event.high_lat;
        }
```

But I get an error:

```
 [InvalidParameterType: Expected params.ExpressionAttributeValues to be a map]
  message: 'Expected params.ExpressionAttributeValues to be a map',
```

Anyone know how to solve it?

My whole code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {


   var params = {
    TableName: "Events", //"StreamsLambdaTable",
    ProjectionExpression: "ID, description, endDate, imagePath, locationLat, locationLon, #nm, startDate, #tp, userLimit",  //specifies the attributes you want in the scan result.
    FilterExpression: "locationLon between :lower_lon and :higher_lon and locationLat between :lower_lat and :higher_lat",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#nm": "name",
        "#tp": "type",
    },

     ExclusiveStartKey: {
       "ID": {"S": event.LastEvaluatedKey}
     },

    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":lower_lon": {"N": event.low_lon},
        ":higher_lon": {"N": event.high_lon}, 
        ":lower_lat": {"N": event.low_lat}
    }
};


if (typeof event.high_lat != "undefined") {
            params.ExpressionAttributeValues = event.high_lat;
        }


  db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } 
    else {
      data.Items.forEach(function(record) {
           console.log(
                record.name.S + "");
        });
        context.succeed(data.Items);


      }
  });
};
```

Example of code sent from android app:

```
{
  "low_lon": "16",
  "high_lon": "17",
  "low_lat": "52",
  "high_lat": "53"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blowing away your entire ExpressionAttributeValues map with a single value. You just need to look at the code you wrote above to see how you should add values to the ExpressionAttributeValues map.

Change this:

```
params.ExpressionAttributeValues = event.high_lat;
```

To this:

```
params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":higher_lat"] = {"N": event.high_lat};
```

Comment: Now i get such an error:   { [ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: "high_lat"]
  message: 'ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: "high_lat"',

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the syntax slightly. See my updated answer.

Comment: Better but now I get:     [ValidationException: Invalid FilterExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :higher_lat]
  message: 'Invalid FilterExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :higher_lat',

Comment: I assume the names like ":lower_lon" and ":higher_lat" aren't actual property names in your table. You need to add the mapping of each name in `ExpressionAttributeNames`. Add `":high_lat" = "high_lat"`, `":low_lat" = "low_lat"`, etc.

Comment: I don't even have such properties in my table. My table contains location latitude and longitude. low_lat, high_lat, etc are values (low latitude value, high latitude value)  sent from android to find suitable items in DataBase and send them back to android app.

Comment: Perfect! That fixed the problem! Thank you